# Using sqlalchemy how invoke a function that return a table

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, user-defined-functions, postgresql-9.2

I haven't find a way to return data from a postgres function that return a TABLE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION doc_codes(device_id TEXT) RETURNS TABLE("name" TEXT, "suffix" TEXT) AS $$
    SELECT name, prefix_fordevice(name,  device_id) AS pf FROM doccode;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Using:

```
    f = sq.sql.text("SELECT name, suffix FROM doc_codes(:deviceId)")

    return self.con.execute(f, deviceId=deviceId)
```

Or

```
    f = sq.sql.func.doc_codes(deviceId, type_=types.String)

    return self.con.execute(
        select([sq.Column('name', types.String), sq.Column('suffix', types.String)]). \
            select_from(f)
    ).fetchall()
```

I get the error `(ProgrammingError) a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"`.

Using `f = sq.sql.func.doc_code(deviceId, type_=types.String)` I get `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts` and the generated `SQL is SELECT doc_code('1') AS doc_code_1`, instead of `SELECT * FROM`.

If a generate a table, I can't pass the deviceId to the table name... now what I can do?

Comment: Are you *sure* you defined your function as `RETURNS TABLE (...)` not `RETURNS SETOF RECORD` ?

Comment: Damm, that was it. The code in the DB was not up-to-date. However, how do it with SET OF RECORD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function definition must actually be `RETURNS SETOF RECORD` not `RETURNS TABLE` to produce that error.

If you actually needed to do it with `RETURNS SETOF RECORD`, you must call it with a column-definition list, like the error message says:

> a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"

See [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html). You can either use `OUT` parameters (equivalent to `RETURNS TABLE`), or call with a col-list, eg:

```
SELECT name, suffix
FROM doc_codes(:deviceId) AS dc("name" TEXT, "suffix" TEXT)
```